# How to play videos with TrueHD audio tracks on linux?

Tags: audio, video, vlc, media, mediaplayer

I have an issue with watching videos nowadays which come with 'Dolby TrueHD 7.1' sound tracks. For years I always used [VideoLAN's VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) for almost everything without any issues.

However, recently I tried to watch a video which comes with TrueHD audio and it simply does not work out with VLC. I'm not the only one with that issue, some user even [uploaded an sample to youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkaR62mV5Eo). I'm having the exact same issue.

Now, everyone in the forums or comment threads knows the issue is VLC-related and they recommend various players like PotPlayer or MPC-HC. But these mediaplayers are not available for Linux systems.

I'm on ArchLinux. Does anyone have a workaround to fix TrueHD with VLC? I also tried mplayer but it also has issues with the playback.

Answer (score 0):

I have no fix for VLC handy, but I noticed the commandline player [MPV](https://mpv.io/) is capabale of playing TrueHD audio without any issues.

[image: mpv player]